# How to display local repository content?

Tags: github, git-bash

I am new to github stuff. Currently using git bash as a CLI to communicate to remote repository I am working on. For now I do comprehend differences in between working directory and local repository the one I've just cloned to local working directory from my Github. My working directory is `~/My-Github-Project (master)` within this local directory there is one local repository named as "new_repo" which I is displayed by this command: `git ls-files` That **new_repo** as a local repository-like directory has its own subdirectories (subfolders).

The question of mine would be:
What command(s) have I to follow on git bash to display new_repo subdirectories? i. e. the content of the new_repo?

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer to my question accidently, steps to follow are:

1. `cd ~/My-Github-Project/new_repo` # or git bash straight away from local repository
2. `git ls-files` # ls-files command shows files and (or) folders if any; it also could be due to files not been added (tracked, staged) yet. To do so to be visible follow this command: `git add -a`, after repeat the command `git ls-files` # now files should be visible within.